# Beautifulsoup html parsing corrupts a <link> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I'm parsing html code from a rss page, using beautiful soup. How do I preserve the link tags?

The code most promising code is:

```
python
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://advisories.ncsc.nl/rss/advisories'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html_doc= uh.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

I tried `import lxml` and switch the code to 
    `python soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'xml')`
but that gave me an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

I expect the result to be 
`<link>https://someurl.org</link>`but the output is `<link/>someurl.org`

Comment: What result? You don't do anything with the `soup`.

Comment: The result from `print(soup)`, Should've added that.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to parse an [rss feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS), for that you can use [feedparser](https://pypi.org/project/feedparser/), i.e.:

```
import feedparser, requests
feed_xml = requests.get("https://advisories.ncsc.nl/rss/advisories").text
feed = feedparser.parse(feed_xml)
print ('Number of RSS posts :', len(feed.entries))
for entry in feed.entries:
    print (entry.title)
    print (entry.link)
    print (entry.description)
```

---

Output:

```
Number of RSS posts : 25
NCSC-2019-0098 [1.02] [H/M] Kwetsbaarheid verholpen in libreoffice
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/advisory?id=NCSC-2019-0098
Een kwaadwillende kan de kwetsbaarheid mogelijk misbruiken om willekeurige code uit te voeren onder de rechten van een gebruiker.
...
```

---

Install `feedparser` using `pip`:

```
pip install feedparser
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the parser to **`xml`** fixes the `<link>` tag:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://advisories.ncsc.nl/rss/advisories'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html_doc= uh.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'xml')    # <-- changing to 'xml'

for link in soup.select('link'):
    print(link.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/rss/advisories
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/advisory?id=NCSC-2019-0098
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/advisory?id=NCSC-2019-0584
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/advisory?id=NCSC-2019-0511
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/advisory?id=NCSC-2019-0583
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/advisory?id=NCSC-2019-0560
https://advisories.ncsc.nl/advisory?id=NCSC-2019-0546

...and so on.
```